# Getting the average of a time(7) field from a table in SQLServer

Tags: t-sql, time

I have a table in a SQLServer database with a field called "TimeTaken" which is of Data Type time(7).  I want to be able to show the average of a number of these rows in a report but my efforts to date keep getting errors "Explicit conversion from data type time to float is not allowed".

Any ideas on the right format to use here as most examples online seem to relate to DateTime data type or getting the diff between 2 times etc. which is not what i'm looking for.

```
AVG(CAST(s.TimeTaken AS FLOAT)) AS 'Average Time to Play Hole'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Time is invalid datatype for finding Average**, So try like below...

```
Cast(DateAdd( ms,avg(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', s.TimeTaken)), '00:00:00' )  as time) as 'Average Time to Play Hole'
```